# How to get the value of autoincrement of last row at the insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, get

I have googled this problem one week and no thing useful I think am not using the correct word

I am using SQL Server 2008 with t-sql and my need is to optimise my function when I insert a new row.

I have a table with first column is the key of integer autoincrement type and other columns are just for information

When we do an insert, SQL Server increments the key automatically and I have to do a select max to get the value, so is there a way like a global variable like `@@IDENTITY` or a function to avoid the begin end transaction and select max

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

```
-- do insert

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Which will give you:

> The last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger,
>   function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if
>   they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

Comment: What happens though if lots of insert statements could happen essentially at the same time? Could this give the wrong ID inserted e.g. from a consequent insert?

Comment: @Applez00800 No, it won't give the wrong ID, it will return the correct id for each transaction.

Answer (score 8):

Just ran the code:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('Joe');
SELECT ID AS LastID FROM Persons WHERE ID = @@Identity;
```

and it also works!

Comment: What is happening if from another thread make another insertion between those two query?

Comment: @user2983041 that's what transactions are for

Answer (score 4):

What about this for last auto increment value

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tableName')-IDENT_INCR('tableName');
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to use @@Identity, because I was inserting into a view.  It seems that SCOPE_IDENTITY only works for ones you have explicitly created.

See here:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

> @@IDENTITY will return the last identity value entered into a table in
>   your current session. While @@IDENTITY is limited to the current
>   session, it is not limited to the current scope. If you have a trigger
>   on a table that causes an identity to be created in another table, you
>   will get the identity that was created last, even if it was the
>   trigger that created it.