# Finding what value was inserted into an auto-incrementing field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

- `Rooms`:

  - `ID` (auto-incrementing primary key, `int`)
  - `Topic` (`varchar(50)`)
  - `MangerId` (`varchar(50)`)
- `Rooms_Users`:

  - `UserId` (`varchar(50)`)
  - `RoomId` (`varchar(50)`)
  - both fields together are the primary key

I want to insert a room but I also must insert the manger to the table `rooms_users`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Creat_Room]  @MangerId varchar(50) ,@Topic varchar(50)
    AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT 
    insert into Rooms(ManagerId,Topic) values(@MangerId,@Topic)
    insert into Rooms_Users(UserId,RoomId) values(@MangerId,?????????????)
END
```

The `?????????????` is the problem: I don't know what to put here i want to put the roomid i insert above.

Comment: In this case you can use [Scope_Identity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx?ppud=4).  You would be wise to heed aweis' advice and learn about the `output` clause for handling many other cases.

Comment: the Scope_Identity() helped me alot, and iam going to learn the output clause in order to get better and better :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value of autoincrement of last row at the insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451070/how-to-get-the-value-of-autoincrement-of-last-row-at-the-insert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Create_Room]  
    @ManagerId varchar(50), 
    @Topic varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewRoomID INT

    insert into Rooms(ManagerId, Topic) values(@MangerId, @Topic)
    SELECT @NewRoomID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    insert into Rooms_Users(UserId, RoomId) values(@ManagerId, @NewRoomID)
END
```

This function will return the last inserted `IDENTITY` value in this particular scope - the scope of your stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `output` clause. Look at MSDN here: [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Example:

```
declare @tbl table
(
    NewID int
)

insert into Rooms(ManagerId,Topic)
output inserted.ID into @tbl
values(@MangerId,@Topic)
```

Then the table variable will contains the new id given to the row you inserted

Comment: +1, but you should mention that it won't work on tables with triggers.