# Insert Auto-Generated ID Into ForeignKey Column Using Parametrized Queries

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2012, parameterized-query

Unsure how to approach this using SQL parametrized queries. I can currently insert data (a customer in this scenario) into an SQL table and let the database generate and handle the primary key ID's rather than insert an ID manually along with the rest of the attributes.

My question is how would I insert this auto-generated ID into another table to it's related foreign-key column using parametrized queries? An example would be if the second table was for bookings and it had to get the ID value (Customer table) of the customer who made the booking and insert it into the FK ID column in the Booking table.

I have looked at code online and on Stack Overflow and it isn't quite what I am looking for as they are either using SQL procedures in the database designer or dealing with manually inserted ID's.

Example code I wrote:

```
//Insert CustomerID into TestTable
public void AddCustomerIdToForeignKeyColumnInNewTable()
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    String query;

    query = "INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (@CustomerID)";
    SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", whateverIdValueGoesHere);
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exception e = ex;
        myConnection.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: It depends on what back-end SQL database you are using. Most of them can get the last inserted auto-generated ID after a query using another query, then you can use this in other places. If you tell us what back-end you are using, we can probably tell you how to get the ID of the record you just inserted. Either way you don't insert the ID column of the database.

Comment: I am unsure of what you mean. I am using SQL Server created through Visual Studio 2012 if that is what you meant by back-end database?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451070/how-to-get-the-value-of-autoincrement-of-last-row-at-the-insert

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will have a look at it and see if it can help and hope my question is not a duplicate. But my SQL Server is Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition (64-bit), 11.0.2100 RTM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 Select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Right after the insert statement.

In other words:

```
query = "INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (@CustomerID); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
```

And then:

```
 var cid= dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

cid will contain the value of the Customer ID generated by the database

Comment: Is Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() part of the string query?

Comment: I am getting a connection issue with ExecuteScalar.

"ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."

I am having a look around to see what it might be that is causing it as my connection to the db seems to be open.

**Got it working but the TestTable does not update with the new data**

Comment: you need to add `myConnection.Open();` before `ExecuteScalar`.. :)

Comment: Anytime.. :) Happy Coding.. :)