# How to get last inserted using in C#?

Tags: c#

This is the code I tried. I want add all the student names using last inserted id.

```
string name = textBox2.Text;
string insert = "insert into details values('"+name+"')";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Record added");
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: please write above code using last inserted id please i need today itself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451070/how-to-get-the-value-of-autoincrement-of-last-row-at-the-insert

Comment: I have still not understood your question. Presenting a problem is equally skillful as solving it.

Comment: Then please **explain in CLEAR English** what it is you're really looking for!! This question is more than unclear......

Comment: i am going to delveoping student registation system. each student have unique id. some thing we might delete one record of the student. my id will be getting wrong. so that id if i entering record once the record has been added into the database. throw the last insert id to overcome of problem.

Comment: The question is clear enough. You need to combine your INSERT with SCOPE_IDENTITY, see the 2nd answer under the duplicate. Also use parametrized queries.

Comment: In MySQL:

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
In SQL Server:

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
In Oracle:

SELECT SEQNAME.CURRVAL FROM DUAL;
In PostgreSQL:

SELECT lastval();

Comment: I think we should be teaching `OUTPUT` to retrieve identity values instead of `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Answer (score -2):

You can make like this

Fast code example:

```
    string name = "jhon";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("insert into details values(ISNULL((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM details),0)+1,'{0}')", name);
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

I Added picture to show it`s working (of course I agree auto_increment is the best way - but I write this type of example to support fast Loshini Loganathan) [image]

Comment: this code is not working

Comment: This won't work unless you turn on `IDENTITY INSERT`, but what you are attempting to do is the exact worst way to get the inserted id.

Comment: @Crowcoder minus two points :/

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that comment, one can only downvote once so it wasn't just me. And, your example is not using auto increment so would not not work for the OP who is using auto increment.

Comment: @Crowcoder your explanation it`s ok. for the OP who is using auto increment this will not work. I didn`t read this correct :) but I tried help ;)

Comment: I understand, and I mean no offense but this is not helpful. It is a very common mistake to increment this way. You may get away with it on a single user system but as soon as you add another concurrent user you risk data corruption and errors. The downvote is a warning to Googler's who find this and maybe try it.