# How to transfer trigger Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

```
create trigger TIB_ESTOQUE before insert
on ESTOQUE for each row
begin
    --  Column "CODIGO" uses sequence S_ESTOQUE
    select S_ESTOQUE.NEXTVAL INTO :new.CODIGO from dual;
end;
```

Comment: Tip 1: create a dual table.

Comment: That looks like you would want to use a sequence in sql server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql Also, there is no such thing as a before trigger in sql server.

Comment: Just creating the dual table does not go forward, because I need the trigger to get the new sequence code with each line that is inserted.

the dual function e: new does not have in SQL Server.

Comment: the sequence has already been created

CREATE SEQUENCE S_ESTOQUE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

the select of the sequence is thus NEXT VALUE FOR S_ESTOQUE;

but the Into: new function does not know how to do it in SQL Server

Comment: In sql server you are going to have to change your mindset. Triggers fire once per operation, not once per row. As such triggers needs to handle entire sets of data. We also want to avoid loops because they are horrible for performance. The kind of thing you are doing would probably be best in the insert stored procedure instead of a trigger. Or just use an identity since this is simply an incremental number for each row.

Comment: 2 Sean Lange: I would oppose statement "fire once per operation". There are statement level triggers and row level triggers (as specified in question by "for each row".

Comment: I guess this trigger is used for auto increment on a column. In this case you don't need this trigger - just change that column to [auto increment](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp).

Comment: If your transaction is more complex: you insert a row, then you use this value for something else as well, then there are [various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451070/how-to-get-the-value-of-autoincrement-of-last-row-at-the-insert) how it could be accessed

Comment: One of the few MSSQL features not in Oracle which I have lusted after has been its auto-incrementing column. ( It's arrived in 12c ). Anyway you should definitely port all your sequences to use `identity` columns instead.