# How can i set the id from one table to another table

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, desktop-application

I have a question, let's say I have two tables I am doing an insert operation to the first table with the stored procedure, but how do I insert the auto incrementing ID in the first table in the other table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of autoincrement of last row at the insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451070/how-to-get-the-value-of-autoincrement-of-last-row-at-the-insert)

Answer (score 0):

Would be good if you provided one example of what you are trying to achieve.

To get the inserted Id by the store procedure, you could use SCOPE_IDENTITY.

**SCOPE_IDENTITY()**: returns the last identity value generated in the current scope.

For instance:

```
INSERT INTO.... VALUES(); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

This query will insert into a the given table and will return the id inserted.

You can also use **Select @@IDENTITY**, this will return the last id inserted regardless the scope.

```
INSERT INTO.... VALUES(); SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```